# How to store all child fragment classes to the parent class' instance

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, architecture

I'm working on a "home feed"-like feature where there's a main `Fragment` with several other fragments added to its layout, making up the content page. I'd like the main fragment class to be able to instanstiate all the fragment classes that inherit from a certain parent fragment class. This way the code would be more dynamic instead of adding a bunch of `<fragment>` tags to my xml files.

I'm kinda stuck on making up a decent architecture. How would you go on about doing this?

UPDATE:
Here's what I'm basically trying to do, but don't know how:

```
public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View parentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        // Get fragments and dynamically add them to
        // the FeedFragment's layout
        getEntryFragmentsList();
        // ...

        return parentView;
    }
}

public abstract class FeedEntryFragment extends Fragment {
   // Somehow add fragment to list of entry fragments
}

public class TestFragment extends FeedEntryFragment {
    // Already added to list of entry fragments
}
```

Comment: Post some codes please.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that possible to decrease the count of xmls by inheritance. I think you should try to split your xml configurations and use some `<merge>` or `<include>` to build the full one from the parts.

May be I can provide more help if you will describe your problem in more details.

Comment: Sure. So I basically want the FeedEntryFragments that make up the content of the home feed to be dynamically added for the sake of tailoring the content to the user. Let's say there's 10 classes that implement FeedEntryFragment and they have different categories such as "recommended", "trending". I could solve this by adding a bunch of new XYEntryFragment()s in the feed fragment's code, but I'm not sure if that would be an elegant solution. Thus I want the classes that inherit from FeedEntryFragment to be seen in the home fragment without manually instanstiating all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout) to add fragment(s) dynamically by using the [FragmentTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction).

You can also use a [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager) with tabs or bottom tabs to show multiple fragments. Please check [sample](https://github.com/pranavpandey/dynamic-support/tree/master/sample) from my [Dynamic Support](https://github.com/pranavpandey/dynamic-support) library for the complete code.

---

**Abstract fragments**
[DynamicFragment](https://github.com/pranavpandey/dynamic-support/blob/master/dynamic-support/src/main/java/com/pranavpandey/android/dynamic/support/fragment/DynamicFragment.java) - Abstract base fragment from the Dynamic support library.
[DynamicViewPagerFragment](https://github.com/pranavpandey/dynamic-support/blob/master/dynamic-support/src/main/java/com/pranavpandey/android/dynamic/support/fragment/DynamicViewPagerFragment.java) - Abstract fragment which extends the DynamicFragment to implement the ViewPager functionality.

**Implementation**
[HomeFragment](https://github.com/pranavpandey/dynamic-support/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/pranavpandey/android/dynamic/support/sample/fragment/HomeFragment.kt) - Sample fragment extends the DynamicFragment to implement the home screen.
[SettingsFragment](https://github.com/pranavpandey/dynamic-support/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/pranavpandey/android/dynamic/support/sample/fragment/SettingsFragment.kt) - Sample fragment extends the DynamicViewPagerFragment to implement the settings functionality using multiple fragments inside a view pager.

**Tutorial Implementation**
This better suits your need. [TutorialActivity](https://github.com/pranavpandey/dynamic-support/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/pranavpandey/android/dynamic/support/sample/activity/TutorialActivity.kt) returns a list of fragments to be displayed inside a ViewPager.

[DynamicSimpleTutorial](https://github.com/pranavpandey/dynamic-support/blob/master/dynamic-support/src/main/java/com/pranavpandey/android/dynamic/support/tutorial/DynamicSimpleTutorial.java) generates a [DynamicTutorialFragment](https://github.com/pranavpandey/dynamic-support/blob/master/dynamic-support/src/main/java/com/pranavpandey/android/dynamic/support/tutorial/fragment/DynamicTutorialFragment.java) according to the supplied parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't phrase my question clearly. I don't have problems with adding existing fragments to the other fragment. My issue is that I don't know how to "automatically" instanstiate all the fragment classes that inherit from FeedEntryFragment from the main FeedFragment, without polluting my code with a bunch of new XYEntryFragment()s.

Comment: @Cerberos I have added the tutorial implementation to better explain your need.